# How do I turn my screen upside down?

Tags: screen

I got my raspberry Pi a case which protects it well and to fix it all together you have to put the screen in a specific position so it all fits in and I don't know how to invert the display so I can use the case to its maximum potential, can anyone help me plz?

Comment: I googled "raspberry pi invert display" and was rewarded with this post ... from the Pi forum:  https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=108&t=120793   Although it talks about rotating 90o, it also covers 180o.

Answer (score 2):

Include the `display_rotate` in `config.txt`. I use `display_rotate=3` to rotate 90°. I think 2 is 180°.

Comment: According to https://support.thepihut.com/hc/en-us/articles/115002072865-Official-touchscreen-is-upside-down , lcd_rotate works better: Don't use the documented display_rotate, it performs a performance expensive rotation of the screen and does not rotate the touch input.

Answer (score 2):

Put "lcd_rotate=2" in /boot/config.txt and the screen will turn upside-down.

When the original software, cases and everything else was designed for the screen, no one noticed they'd got it the wrong way up. (oops!)

A software fix was put in place to flip it the other way, but some cases had already been designed for it. So the "lcd_rotate=2" option was added to flip the image and touchscreen "upside-down" so it works in those cases.

The GL driver in Stretch is not compatible with "lcd_rotate = 2" and you must disable it.

It works with the official Raspberry Pi Foundation 7" display.

Comment: Welcome to SE Raspberry Pi! While this suggestion is helpful, the original post (OP) was over two years ago, before Stretch was released -- and the OP does not include OS version information. Be careful when answering old questions.

Comment: Worked. But 'lcd_rotate = 2' does not work, because of the spaces.